# Dynamically Create new Matrix and a Table for each group and add page breaks

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have this problem where in a group there are couple of question defined out of which one question has a descriptive answer and rest are numbers.
There are 3 such groups, which can grow in the future.
I want to generate a report where I display the result of the group in one page but should generate for every group dynamically.

The Output would look like this:

---

```
 |Group_Category|     |    {Matrix Style; }
 |Question      |Value|


 |Group_Category|                  |   {Table}
 |(+)Question   |Descriptive Answer|
```

---

So this has to be repeated for each group on different pages.
Can anyone please help me out

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's give you a simple example to describe how this potentially could be done.

1. Let's create a datasource, for the purpose of this example it does not matter at all as all the data will be self contained in the example.
2. Populate a dataset with below:

   ```
   DECLARE @Table TABLE (personID int IDENTITY, person varchar(8), 
   orders int, level1 int, level2 int); 

   INSERT INTO @Table VALUES    ('Brett', 10, 1, 1), ('John', 20, 1, 1), 
   ('Peter', 15, 2, 1), ('Jessica', 25, 2, 1), ('Eddie', 7, 3, 1), 
   ('Jimi', 50, 3, 1), ('Robert', 5, 1, 2)

   SELECT *
   FROM @Table
   ```
3. Create an object of 'Table' from your Toolbox and insert only the 'person' value on the lower left cell, it should populate a header as well.  Do the same for the 'orders' value on the cell next to it.  Delete the column to the right.  You should now have four populated cells, two value cells with headers.
4. For a grouping let's go to the lower left of your 'Design' view in Visual Studio and you should see a 'Row Groups' that currently only has '=Details'(or similar) in it.  Right Click that and hit 'Add Parent'.  Select group on 'level1' and click 'Add Group Header'.  You now should see another row added but it is blank with detail EXCEPT on the farthest left column.  To the left of that in the gray block area you will see a ( that will encompass both rows indicating they are 'GROUPED'.
5. You may do step 4 again except with two changes.  Right Click on level1 this time to add a parent to that.  Then group on 'level2' instead.
6. If you want to page break on the second level grouping select 'level2'(or generic equivalent name of that grouping) click F4.  Expand the 'PageBreak' under properties.  Change 'BreakLocation' to be 'Start'.  Your report will now Page Break before your highest level grouping.

You do not need to worry about adding more groups with SSRS.  You merely need to worry that they get distinguished in the correct columns to work dynamically.  If I added more data to my table later to show a grouping other than 1, 2 or 3 for level1, SSRS will catch it, I don't have to worry about that.

EDIT if you have different types of data together with different datasets remember you can use a UNION to easily get past this problem:

EG:

```
Select 'I am strings' as group1, 'Descriptive String' as Detail
from dataset1
UNION
Select 'I am numbers', cast(1 as varchar(64))
from dataset2
```

When SSRS interprets 'group1' it only sees two different values and can thus group on them.  It does not care about the underlying SQL where you put two different types together.  As long as you cast them that the engine can interpret it, it should not matter.

Comment: Is there a way I can use Loops on SSRS and achieve this?

Comment: I am not getting what you are attempting to do from your description that needs to do loops.  Your datasets can grow from your queries exponentially and still have a matrix or tabular table handle the groupings.  If you keep the list very generic like: "ID, GroupExplain, Description"  You may populate the group and description column with whatever you like and have them both grow indefinitely.

Comment: So you are saying that the growth of the report(No of Tables in matrix or Tabular form) is dependent on the no of groups available from the query itself?

Comment: Exactly.  If I have a simple dataset with columns ID, group, DateCreated.  If I populate it with 5 rows that have two different groups but then later down the road I have 4 more groups.  I don't have to write anything differently.  I merely have to capture it the correct way.  The SQL creating the dataset should do all the work for that part of SSRS.

Comment: The Group contains a matrix style and a tabular style. It is displaying the Matrix style table first and after populating all the groups it is showing the Tabular style group wise.

Comment: You are nesting a tabular table in a matrix?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do that. Is there a solution to that.

Comment: You could do all the logic in a single matrix unless you have two separate datasets.  Grouping relates to an object at a time so breaking out a page or multi level grouping may be more difficult than necessary if you are nesting objects.  I generally only nest objects if they are a different datasets.

Comment: Thank you very much for the Support and Answering my questions.

Comment: Can you please tell me if I use 2 datasets which has a common Group Name how can I To display and Connect both Matrix and Tabular on same page.

Comment: It would be easier to just have one dataset that does joins or unions to combine it and then have SSRS present it from two.  Can you do that with the datasets you have?

Comment: Yes,I can have one DataSet.

Comment: I would do that, your complexity and maintenance grows exponentially with doing grouping with nested objects of tables, graphs, or sub reports.

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve my above problem by using Rectangle property.

Basically defined the

"**Group_Category**" in side the rectangle and then placed a **Matrix** and a **Table** inside the rectangle below the category. That helped me to have a parent group on the page and have other groups and Calculation inside.

I fields and data has to come or populate  from the same Dataset.